# Python, searching all objects in a class for a keyword, return true

Tags: python, oop, search

new poster here, not new to searching for other people answers...

I am quite new to programming and Python, and have been getting on ok, however I have been avoiding OOP on my previous programs as I couldn't make much sense of it.

I have watched a few tutorials and figured the only way I will truly learn it is by doing it in practice.

I believe I could likely make this program using a standard dict, but I am doing this as a learning exercise more than anything else.

I am attempting to make a program that stores meals as one object containing "name", "ingredients", "dietary info", and "tags" that enables me to search for a keyword in a selected one of these categories and return the results.

Once I get a true return I can manipulate this to show more of the class or whatever, at the moment my program just terminates without printing the search_term indicating a false return despite my checking my spelling.

Just trying to get past this speed bump so I can progress with my program.  Also any feedback on the my code so far being too long winded etc. And how to consolidate it is very much welcome.

Apologies for the essay!

````
   class Meal(object):
     def __init__(self, name, ingredients, dietary, tags):
        self.name = name
        self.ingredients = ingredients
        self.dietary = dietary
        self.tags = tags

m1 = Meal ("Carbonara", ("Pasta", "Eggs", "Garlic", "Mushrooms", "Parmesan cheese"), ("Vegetarian", "Gluten-free(optional)"),("Quick", "Easy"))
m2 = Meal ("Avocado Pasta", ("Avocado", "Pasta", "Basil", "Lime", "Garlic", "Parmesan cheese", "Olive oil"), ("Vegetarian", "Gluten-free(optional)"),("Quick", "Easy"))

print("What category would you like to search? ")
print("1) Meal name\n2)Ingredient\n3)Specific diet\n4)Smart tag")
category = int(input("Select a number: "))
if category == 1:
    search_term = input("what would you like to search for?")
    for x in m1.name:
        if x == search_term:
            print (search_term)
            break
        elif x != search_term:
            for x in m2.name:
                if x == search_term:
                    print(search_term)
                    break
            else:
                x = None```
````

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am assuming you need to search for a name in a list of Meal items.

A better approach is to create a list of Meal items

So something like this should work

```
meal_list = [m1,m2]
```

Then in the actual code.

```
if category == 1:
    search_term = input("what would you like to search for?")
    #Loop over your list of Meal items
    for x in meal_list:
        if x.name == search_term:
            print(search_term)
            break
        else:
            #Whatever you want to do here
```

Comment: That's done it, thank you very much for the clear reply (not to mention quick)  the list consolidates the search to a much shorter piece of code and I was missing the .name argument in the search term.

Answer (score 0):

In python strings are iterable and looping over it will basically take you char by char through it.

So in your piece of code specifically:

> for x in m1.name:

This actually will go through "Carbonara" and compare 'C', 'a', ... to your search term, which I assume is not what you want.

Alternatively if you were looking to search through ingredients then it's just a misstype, and it should be m1.ingredients instead.

Answer (score 0):

If you wanna improve your code a little bit you can write something like this:

```
class Meal():
    def __init__(self, name, ingredients, dietary, tags):
        self.name = name
        self.ingredients = ingredients
        self.dietary = dietary
        self.tags = tags

    def get_attr(self, num):
        if num == '1':
            return self.name
        elif num == '2':
            return self.ingredients
        elif num == '3':
            return self.dietary
        elif num == '4':
            return self.tags

m1 = Meal ("Carbonara", ("Pasta", "Eggs", "Garlic", "Mushrooms", "Parmesan cheese"), ("Vegetarian", "Gluten-free(optional)"),("Quick", "Easy"))
m2 = Meal ("Avocado Pasta", ("Avocado", "Pasta", "Basil", "Lime", "Garlic", "Parmesan cheese", "Olive oil"), ("Vegetarian", "Gluten-free(optional)"),("Quick", "Easy"))

meal_objects = {
    m1.name: m1,
    m2.name: m2
}

search_term = input("what would you like to search for?\n")

if meal_objects.get(search_term): # To make sure that search_term is exist in meal_objects otherwise we can get error
    print("\nWhat category would you like to search? ")
    print("1)Meal name\n2)Ingredient\n3)Specific diet\n4)Smart tag")
    category = input("Select a number: ")
    category_value = meal_objects[search_term].get_attr(category)
    print(f'\n{category_value}') if category_value else print('\nWrong value of category')
else:
    print('Meal not found.')
```

You should try to create more class methods to make your code easier to understand and to use.